# Prolog rules structure and its difference

Tags: prolog, rules

I'm confused about the structure of how my Prolog rules should be written.

Lets say, I want to state that only birds can fly.

Should my rule be written as

```
fly(X):- bird(X).
```

or

```
bird(X):-fly(X).
```

What is the difference in meaning between them?
Furthermore, do I need to explicitly state that if the entity is not a bird, it cannot fly?

Also, if I wish to say...
I can either go to the zoo or the library. Either zoo or library, but not both. How should it be?
I am assuming it to be..

```
go_there(X,Place):-
   go_there(X,zoo),
   go_there(X,library).
```

Please go gentle on me, as this is my first try with Prolog programming! Thank you!

Comment: This isn't really specific to SWI Prolog, is it?

Comment: @lurker, I have some unresolved issue with my own codes in SWI-prolog. 

I wish to have someone who can point out where I went wrong in terms of my logic... Do you think you can help out here? :)

Comment: If you have another specific issue with your code, can you formulate it into another question you can post on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I will formulate it to another question and edit this post. Will that be fine?

Comment: You should create a new question, not add more to this question. Otherwise, it will confuse the whole question/answer sequence in this thread. If you need to refer back to this question, you can use a hyperlink in your new question.

Comment: @lurker, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152389/where-did-my-logic-went-wrong-using-swi-prolog

This is the new question and I hope to get your response there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that *only birds can fly* can be expressed as, *if a creature can fly, then it must be a bird*. Depending upon the semantics of this terse phrase, it might leave open the possibility that there could be some birds that cannot fly.

Therefore, the predicate:

```
fly(X) :- bird(X).
```

Would not be correct. This says that, *if `X` is a bird, then `X` can fly*, which is not what the *only birds can fly* says, logically.

The more direct translation to Prolog would then be:

```
bird(X) :- fly(X).
```

It says that, *`X` is a bird if `X` can fly* (or, *if `X` can fly, then `X` must be a bird*).

The exclusivity of *only* would occur due to the *absence* of any other predicate that says some other creature can fly, such as:

```
bee(X) :- fly(X).
```

Regarding the second question:

```
go_there(X,Place):-
   go_there(X,zoo),
   go_there(X,library).
```

This says that, *`X` goes to `Place` if `X` goes to the zoo, and `X` goes to the library*. This doesn't sound at all like, *`X` can either go to the zoo, or to the library, but not both*. I could say something like:

```
go_there(fred, zoo).
go_there(fred, library).
```

These say that `fred` can go to the zoo, or `fred` can go to the library.

And then if I query:

```
go_there(fred, Place).
```

It will yield two different results for `Place`:

```
Place = zoo
Place = library
```

To say that `X` can go to one or the other, but not both, requires qualification. Does this mean within a specific period of time that `X` cannot go to both? Or does it mean that once `X` goes to one, then it can never ever go to the other? Whether the above predicate satisfies the first case is unclear. It depends upon the context. In either case, you'd need to add some Prolog logic to handle either the time aspect, or, if the "forever" case, you'd need a random selection of one or the other, and then have that selection remain persistent from that point forward.

---

In response to additional comments, if you to say:

```
go_there(human(fred), zoo).
go_there(human(fred), library).
```

You are choosing to represent a person, such as `fred`, as a human via a functor, `human/1`. In order to designate `fred` as human, you have to carry the functor around with `fred` and always refer to `fred` as `human(fred)` whenever used in a predicate that is looking for `fred`s membership in the human race. If you wanted to ask if `fred` goes to the zoo, `go_there(fred, zoo).` would fail, unfortunately, because the fact that `fred` is human needs to be a part of the atom representing `fred`. You'd have to query, `go_there(human(fred), zoo)`. To determine if `fred` is human, you would query, `go_there(human(fred), _).` which is also a bit awkward.

Separating the relationships is clearer:

```
go_there(fred, zoo).
go_there(fred, libary).

human(X) :- go_there(X, zoo).
human(X) :- go_there(X, library).
```

Now if you query, `human(fred).`, you get "true". And if you query, `go_there(fred, zoo)` you also get "true".

Comment: Maybe i should have asked the question such that, human can either be a female or a male. Never is a both. Lol.

Comment: If i asked it that way, would it make any difference to the above rules?

Comment: Can I be sure that..

go_there(Human(X),zoo).
go_there(Human(X),library).

is also equivalent to

Human(X) :- go_there(X,zoo).
Human(X) :- go_there(X,library). ?

What I was trying to portray as the knowledge here, is that, if anything goes to either a zoo or a library, it belongs to a human class...

Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: @user3004159, maybe it's a typo, but a functor in Prolog must start with lower case. So you can't have, `Human(X)`. This discussion is too long for a comment, so I'll update my answer.